# Browser get stuck when running loop in mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get an endpoint on `mounted()` and I want to increment id until it is false so I can display all of result on the page

```
  data () {
    return {
      id : 0,
      found : true,
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    while(this.found){
   this.$http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${this.id}`)
    .then((data)=>{
    this.characters = data.body
    this.id++;
    })
    console.log(this.id);
  }
```

Why the browser gets held up? Is something in my loop?

Comment: You are firing async requests that never get resolved as they all wait the `while` loop to finish. And the `while` loop never finishes, since it waits for the async requests to be done.

Comment: how do I finish it?

Comment: And now you've changed it and the `while` loop never finishes because the condition never changes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is something in my loop?

Yes: You never change `this.id` in the loop. That loop just creates HTTP request after HTTP request after HTTP request, because your increment of `this.id` is **inside** your `then` callback, which is asynchronous.

Move the increment outside of the `then` callback so the loop actually finishes.

---

Re your edit replacing `while (this.id <= 10)` with `while (this.found)`, it's the same sort of problem: Nothing ever sets `this.found`.

Comment: Code changed while you were writing this. Now the `while` loop has a different condition that is never changed.

Comment: @Nofel - That just makes it even more clear: Nothing ever sets `this.found` in the loop.

Comment: isn't ths.found is false when there r no results? that was the gist of it.

Comment: @Nofel nothing ever updates `this.found`, so it will never become `false`.

Comment: @Nofel - I don't know if `this.$http.get` reaches out to set `this.found` (I don't use Vue.js), but again, HTTP requests are **asynchronous**, so even if `this.$http.get` does that when it gets a 404 or similar, it can't do that while your loop is running. It would need to do that in an async completion handler, and nothing else in the same JavaScript realm (loosely: window/tab) can run while your loop is running because there's only one thread per realm.